# AJAX function(this)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am not familiar with ajax, I am in the process of learning, but as far as I know, it utilizes javascript to access the DOM, so my question is, is it possible to put an argument inside a function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc( * * this * * ) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", ""
    test.php ? access = "**+this**", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

Shouldn't this work?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Unless you are doing this as an exercise in learning, I recommend using robust javascript library (e.g. Dojo, jQuery).  They provide ajax facilities that abstract browser differences and provide a much cleaner calling interface.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in JS changes according to the context you are running in. Depending on how you call it, it will change.

Read this article for more information : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",""test.php?access="**+this**",false);
```

This call wouldn't make much sense since `this` refers to an object, but what you're actually attempting to do is string concatenation (adding two strings together).

If you need to make variable calls, use a variable instead of the `this` keyword.

```
function loadXMLDoc(accessVar) {
    ....
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?access=" +accessVar ,false);
}

loadXMLDoc('accessIdentifier'); //passes the value 'accessIdentifier' to your method so it is passed along in the querystring.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  It looks like you're using the example from w3schools.  Be warned, that site is not always the most reliable source. See http://w3fools.com/ for more info.

Look over their code again, as it is taken from their page:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

As you can see, the "on success" code is located within the `onreadystatechange` event handler.  Your example code has three problems: one with the way you're passing a variable, two with the way you use `this`, and three that your response handler won't work as expected.

```
var xmlhttp;
var var1 = 'testdata';
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    handleAjaxResponse(responseText);
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.php?var1="+var1,true);
xmlhttp.send();

function handleAjaxResponse(resp) {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=resp;
}
```

In terms of `this`, it refers to the current scope of execution, a different subject entirely.  It isn't a variable you'd pass via AJAX.

Comment: Chris, but in the code bellow, i can't define my variable, by using loadXMLDoc(variable) because in the code, the var1 variable is defined inicialy, i need to make it volatile by using it on the body like onClick="loadXMLDoc(variable)"; ... Did you understood me ? I am sorry for my rusty engrish.